# C++ main() in a large OOP project

Tags: c++, oop, program-entry-point

This may be a short & simple question, but I've never found a satisfying answer to it:

What code does the main() function usually consist of in a large C++ project? Would it be an incorrect assumption to think that it is usually just initializing a (wrapping) class object and calling a function inside of it to set things off?

Why is main() not a method in the first place? Is it to preserve backwards-compatibility with C?

Comment: The reason it's not a member function is that then you'd need a way to specify what class it's a member function of. C++ has nothing like Java's manifest, and no reflection.

Comment: from a more conceptual level, every program needs an entry point, in the case of "classical" C++ this is within the executable the compiler produces, when the program starts there is no class in existence that main could be a method of.  In interpreted languages the runtime executes first and sets up a context for the application to run in before it starts so the entry point being a method/member of some previously setup class is possible should the language/runtime allow/desire it.

Comment: @Mark: what? The compiler is responsible for emitting code to initialise various things, including static members of classes, before main() executes. To the extent that classes can be said to exist at all at runtime in C++, there are plenty of classes in existence before the entry point is called. There could even be plenty of objects in existence too.

Comment: @onebyone a "standard" c++ compiler emits code to initialize static members and objects its been told to, that some implementations of the stdlibs or a users code may create static members/classes/objects is immaterial to the question.  C++ does not by specification create a root class that main could possibly be a member of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my code, it's basically a constructor call, possibly a method call, and some exception handling. This is the main for own of my projects (headers and comments omitted, and formatting messed up by SO, as usual):

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        CLIHandler ch( argc, argv );
        result = ch.ExecCommand();
    }
    catch( const Exception & ex ) {
        result = ExceptionHandler::HandleMyError( ex );
    }
    catch( const std::exception & ex ) {
        result = ExceptionHandler::HandleOtherError( ex );
    }
    catch( ... ) {
        result = ExceptionHandler::HandleUnknownError();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why not just replace all your `result = ` with `return `?

Comment: Wash your mouth out! Have you never heard of the requirement that in  all well-structured code a function  must have only one exit point???? But to be serious, my way is easier to debug, as you have  a variable to inspect.

Comment: Ah, I see lol. You scared me. I was like, "FUUU- what?!". I guess I've never had to inspect the return variable, my error handler prints it out along with the exception. Otherwise our code is the same.

Comment: +1 for a main I like and encourage everybody to use. Something I use is an exception handler that just call ExceptionHandler::handle() in the catch(...) clause. The handle method re-throw in a try-catch where you have the different exception handling. Simplier ? More readable ? Error handling centralized in a specific class ... Your taste ...

Comment: The "only one exit point" thing was a lot more relevant in C. In C++, with RAII, it's *usually* pointless (and exceptions pretty much undermine it anyway). I can see the point here, in main, though.

Comment: @jalf That was a JOKE! I also encourage the use of multiple exit points - it almost always makes the code clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Mine usually do

- Command-line parsing
- Initialization of top-level objects
- Exception handling
- entering main 'exec' loop

As I understand it, `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is essentially a convention due to the `C` heritage.  Never struck me as odd, but rather as useful. C++ extends C after all ... (and yes there are fine difference but that wasn't the question here).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the reason is backward compatibility. main is the only entry point allowed in a C program producing executables, and therefore in a C++ program.

As for what to do in a C++ main, it depends. In general, I used to:

- perform global initialization (e.g. of the logging subsystem)
- parse command line arguments and define a proper class containing them
- allocate an application object, setting it up etc.
- run the application object (in my case, an infinite loop method. GUI programming)
- do finalization after the object has completed its task.

oh and I forgot the most important part of an application

- show the splashscreen

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: it depends. It may well create a few local objects that are needed for the duration of the program, configure them, tell them about each other and call a long running method on one of them.

A program needs an entry point. If `main` had to be a method on an object, what class type should it be?

With `main` as a global entry point it can choose what to set up.

Answer (score 1):

My main() function often constructs various top-level objects, giving them references to one another. This helps minimize coupling, keeping the exact relationships between the different top-level objects confined to the main.

Often those top-level objects have distinct life cycles, with init(), stop(), and start() methods. The main() function manages getting the objects into the desired running state, waits for whatever indicates it is time to shut down, and then shutting everything down in a controlled fashion. Again, this helps keep things properly decoupled, and keeps top-level life cycle management in one easily understood place. I see this pattern a lot in reactive systems, especially those with a lot of threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static class member function in place of main with the MSVC++ compiler by choosing the entry point in the project settings, under the advanced linker options.

It really depends on your project as to what you want to place in there... if it is small you may as well put message loops, initialization and shutdown code in there. In larger projects you will have to move these into their own classes/functions or less have a monolithic entry point function.

Answer (score 0):

Not all C++ applications are OOP and either way all code requires some entry point to start from.

When I'm writing OOP code, my `main()` tends to include an object instantiation, maybe proceeded by some user input. I do it this way because I feel that the 'work' is meant to be done within an object, otherwise the code isn't written in the 'spirit' of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Really large projects tend not comprise only a single program. Hence there will be several executables each with their own main. In passing, it's quite common for these executables to communicate asynchronously via queues.

Yes each main does tend to be very small, initialising a framework or whatever.

Do you mean why is main() a function rather than a method of class? Well, what class would it be a method of? I think it's mostly C++'s heritage from C, but ... everything got to start somewhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use main for reading in the command line, initializing global variables, and then calling the appropriate functions/methods.